Change Samsung One UI Home Font Size
How can I change the font size or widget font size of One UI Home?
I was trying Theme Park from GoodLock and when I applied the theme I made, it decreased the font size of all home elements, widgets, icon captions, etc. I've tried applying the default theme but it didn't reset the font. Tried resetting One UI Home (Clear Data) but also didn't work. Also I don't seem to find a font size option on Theme Park.
I could increase the system font size, but on other apps it's fine, so I'm not doing that.
My phone is a Samsung S21 with Android 14, One UI 6.0 and One UI Home 15.0.09.1

I do not know about your device.But most samsung devices have the same setting. You can check the settings app.Then go to display>font size and style.Manage your font size and style.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While this might be a valid answer in general, AFAIR, the OP has ruled out this solution: "I could increase the system font size, but on other apps it's fine, so I'm not doing that."
